# How to join two tables in one view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a view where I can see the items that have been planned to be shipped and have not been shipped, and the items have have been shipped but were not planned to. 
In order to do this I have 2 tables with different data in them.

**Table SC (actually shipped):**

```
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
| item_id | source_location | destination_location | shipped_qty |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
| 001     |    California   |    South_Carolina    |      80     |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
| 001     |    California   |    South_Carolina    |      0      |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
| 001     |    California   |         Texas        |      20     |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
| 003     |      Texas      |    South_Carolina    |     200     |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
| 004     |  South_Carolina |         Texas        |      30     |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
| 004     |  South_Carolina |         Texas        |      10     |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

**Table SO (plan to ship items):**

```
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| item_id | source_location | destination_location | planned_order |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| 001     |    California   |    South_Carolina    |      100      |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| 001     |    California   |    South_Carolina    |      100      |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| 001     |    California   |         Texas        |       10      |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| 003     |      Texas      |    South_Carolina    |      200      |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| 004     |  South_Carolina |         Texas        |      300      |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| 004     |  South_Carolina |         Texas        |      50       |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
```

So in this case, for example, since the item 001 has three different planned orders from California to South Carolina, I don't want it to show all the three orders in the view, I want it to be only in one row, but *sum* all the planned orders together, as showed below.

**Desired Outcome:**

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
| item_id |   source_loc   | destination_loc | shipped_qty | planned_qty |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
| 001     |   California   |  South_Carolina |      80     | 200         |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
| 001     |   California   |      Texas      |      20     | 10          |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
| 003     |      Texas     |  South_Carolina |     200     | 200         |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
| 004     | South_Carolina |      Texas      |      40     | 350         |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have tried this so far:

```
SELECT  o.source_location,
        o.destination_location,
        o.item_id,
        o.planned_order,
        c.shipped_qty
        FROM SO_TRANSFER o, SC_TRANSFER c
```

But this hasn't worked since the shipped_qty does not match the item and this code also does not add the orders together.

By the way, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select coalesce(s.item_id, p.item_id) as item_id,
       coalesce(s.source_location, p.source_location) as source_location,
       coalesce(s.destination_location, p.destination_location) as destination_location,
       coalesce(s.shipped_qty, 0) as shipped_qty,
       coalesce(planned_qty, 0) as planned_qty
from (select item_id, source_location, destination_location, sum(shipped_qty) as shipped_qty
      from sc
      group by item_id, source_location, destination_location
     ) s full join
     (select item_id, source_location, destination_location, sum(planned_qty) as planned_qty
      from so
      group by item_id, source_location, destination_location
     ) p
     on s.item_id = p.item_id and
        s.source_location = p.source_location and
        s.destination_location = p.destination_location;
```

Comment: Hello, great answer. Btw, why can't I get the result using single GROUP BY clause? 
I have tried create dummy table and data using table variable in TSQL, and I uses this 
`SELECT A.item_id,A.s_location,A.d_location, 
SUM(A.shp_qty) AS shp_qty,
SUM(B.pln_ord) AS pln_ord
FROM @sc A, @so B
WHERE A.item_id = B.item_id AND A.s_location = B.s_location AND A.d_location = B.d_location
GROUP BY A.item_id,A.s_location,A.d_location`, I got everything correct but the last row. It somehow sum it twice resulting 80 in shp_qty and 700 in pln_ord. Correct result should be 40 and 350.

Comment: How can I add another column, called "open_qty" that is on the SO table?

Comment: @MarkSantos You can modify the code section after `full join ...` to `(select item_id, source_location, destination_location, sum(planned_qty) as planned_qty, sum(open_qty) as open_qty from so group by item_id, source_location, destination_location) p`. And at the select statement, simply add `, coalesce(open_qty,0) as open_qty` after the last select : `coalesce(planned_qty, 0) as planned_qty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.item_id,
       A.source_location AS source_loc,
       A.destination_location AS destination_loc,
       A.shipped_qty,
       B.planned_order
FROM 
      (SELECT item_id,source_location,destination_location,SUM(shipped_qty) 
      AS shipped_qty
      FROM SC GROUP BY item_id,source_location,destination_location) A, 

      (SELECT item_id,source_location,destination_location,SUM(planned_order) 
      AS planned_order
      FROM SO GROUP BY item_id,source_location,destination_location) B

WHERE A.item_id = B.item_id AND 
      A.source_location= B.source_location AND
      A.destination_location= B.destination_location
```

EDIT: I just realize my answer is similar to [Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56535262/7882621), and his answer got more feature such as handling data that exists in one table only using [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in T-SQL and [FULL JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) property. Since I worked 1 hour for this answer, so I will just leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `SELECT` statement, and use that as a table in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT o.source_location,
       o.destination_location,
       o.item_id,
       o.planned_order,
       c.shipped_qty_sum
FROM SO_TRANSFER o
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(shipped_qty) AS shipped_qty_sum,
                   source_location,
                   item_id
            FROM SC_TRANSFER
            GROUP BY source_location, item_id) c
ON o.item_id = c.item_id AND o.source_location = c.source_location
```

Comment: Where did you get the shipped_qty_sum from?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the alias in the subquery. Edited the answer

Comment: I am getting this error message:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
Column 'SC_TRANSFER.source_location' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: My apologies! This is why I shouldn't do answers late at night or without testing! First the server will do the subquery (everything within parenthesis after `INNER JOIN`, and then use the results of that query in the join.

Answer (score 0):

The point is you should SUM(quantity) from each table first, then you can easy JOIN 2 table with condition: 
 `ON so.item_id = sc.item_id AND so.source_loc = sc.source_loc AND so.destination_loc = sc.destination_loc`

Answer (score 0):

The following query will do what you are looking for

```
 Create table #SC(
item_id varchar(50),
source_location varchar(max),
Destination_location varchar(max),
Shipped_qty int)

insert into #SC values('001','california','sourth_carolian',80)
insert into #SC values('001','california','sourth_carolian',0)
insert into #SC values('001','california','Texas',20)
insert into #SC values('003','Texas','sourth_carolian',200)
insert into #SC values('004','sourth_carolian','Texas',30)
insert into #SC values('004','sourth_carolian','Texas',10)
--select * from #SC

Create table #SO(
item_id varchar(50),
source_location varchar(max),
Destination_location varchar(max),
Planned_order int)


insert into #SO values('001','california','sourth_carolian',100)
insert into #SO values('001','california','sourth_carolian',100)
insert into #SO values('001','california','Texas',10)
insert into #SO values('003','Texas','sourth_carolian',200)
insert into #SO values('004','sourth_carolian','Texas',300)
insert into #SO values('004','sourth_carolian','Texas',50)

--select * from #SO


select C.item_id,C.source_location,C.Destination_location, sum(C.Shipped_qty) as Shipped_qty, po.planned_order from #SC  C

outer apply 
(select sum(Planned_order) as planned_order from #SO  
where source_location+Destination_location=C.source_location+C.Destination_location
group by item_id,source_location,Destination_location  ) as PO 

group by C.item_id,C.source_location,C.Destination_location,po.planned_order
```